# Rewriting git history to make crlf consistent

Tags: git, dos

I have a git repository that has a fine variation of LF and CRLF files.

Before making a possible switch, I want to rewrite commits where the parent and the current commit have different LR/CRLF encodings.

So I tried the following "one-liner" (slightly edited) where I try to run `todos` if the parent version of a file contains a CR.

```
$ git filter-branch --tree-filter '
  echo
  P=$GIT_COMMIT^;
  FILES=$(git diff --name-only $P);
  for a in $FILES; do
     if ! git cat-file -e $P:$a; then echo "no parent"; continue; fi;
     if git show $:$a | grep -qUP '\r'; then
        echo "parent is dos";
        todos $a;
     else
        echo "parent is unix";
        fromdos $a;
     fi;
  done' 23498f..HEAD
```

It doesn't work. Can anyone spot the error or give a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I am answering my own question.  The bug in my original solution is that the `FILES` set is wrong because the diff is not taken between the *rewritten* parent and the current commit, but between the *original* parent and the current commit.

When traversing a set of commits like this, the files that need to be changed isn't the set of files touched by a commit, but also the set of files where some parent commit messed up the line endings.

This means that I don't get the correct set of files.  There is a `map` function provided to filter-branch expressions that can transform an "original" rev to the rewritten rev.  When I use that function, it works correctly.

The resulting "one-liner" looks like this:

```
$ git filter-branch -f --tree-filter '                         
    echo "\n $GIT_COMMIT";
    P=$(git rev-parse $GIT_COMMIT^);
    echo $P;
    P=$(map $P);
    echo $P;
    git cat-file commit $GIT_COMMIT;
    FILES=$(git diff --name-only $GIT_COMMIT $P);
    echo "FILES:\n$FILES"; 
    for a in $FILES; do
        git cat-file -e $P:$a > /dev/null 2>&1 || continue;
        if git show $P:$a | grep -qUP '\r'; then
           echo "parent is dos $a";
           todos $a;
        else
           echo "parent is unix $a";
           fromdos $a;
        fi;
    done;
    git add $FILES;' a6d9e..HEAD
```

Most of the aI don't think the last 'git add $FILES' is needed, but that is the command that I used, and I don't want to provide an incorrect answer.

Note: It should also be possible to define `FILES=$(git diff --name-only a6d9e HEAD)` and thus use a fixed set when traversing the commits. That is probably much simpler, but I didn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to re-write history?

Using the built in configuration option helps to make these things transparent.  I have done something similar to this, and for the last few years, working with people on Windows, Mac and Linux systems have yet to have a problem with line endings.

Look at [Dealing With Line Endings](https://plus.google.com/u/0/events/cjott7dmncu02thsad4ucp4p7vo) from GitHub.

Here is what they have to say about configuration files:

> Here's an example .gitattributes file, you can use it as a template for all your repositories:

```
# Set default behaviour, in case users don't have core.autocrlf set.
* text=auto

# Explicitly declare text files we want to always be normalized and converted 
# to native line endings on checkout.
*.c text
*.h text

# Declare files that will always have CRLF line endings on checkout.
*.sln text eol=crlf

# Denote all files that are truly binary and should not be modified.
*.png binary
*.jpg binary The advantage of this is that your end of line configuration now travels with your repository and you don't need to worry about whether or not collaborators have the proper global settings.
```

They go on to talk about what you can do if you have a current repository, and need to apply these settings to it.

Re-normalizing a repository

> After you've set the core.autocrlf option and committed a
>   .gitattributes file, you may find that git wants to commit files that
>   you've not modified. This is because git wants to normalize the line
>   endings for you. The best way to do this is wipe out your working tree
>   (all the files except the .git directory) and then restore them. Make
>   sure you've committed any work before you do this, or it will be lost.

```
git rm --cached -r .
# Remove everything from the index.

git reset --hard
# Write both the index and working directory from git's database.

git add .
# Prepare to make a commit by staging all the files that will get normalized.
# This is your chance to inspect which files were never normalized. You should
# get lots of messages like: "warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in file."

git commit -m "Normalize line endings"
# Commit
```

Comment: My issue is that I *already* have commits that have changed the line ending of files. I don't want that right now.  I found a solution that I am satisfied with that I am adding as an answer.

Comment: That is what the second part of this answer is supposed to address.  When you have a history and need to apply the settings.  Glad you found a solution!