# git filter-branch and gitattributes

Tags: git, newline, gitattributes

I want to convert Windows/mixed line endings in the history of an enterprise git repository into Unix line endings using `git filter-branch`. Since the repository contains some domain specific binary file types, the `.gitattributes` file is quite elaborated, so I would rather use git's own mechanism for EOL conversion as opposed to `dos2unix` scripting like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693512/rewriting-git-history-to-make-crlf-consistent).

I managed to do the conversion using the procedure that I describe in https://github.com/cnaj/demo-crlf-rewrite/tree/so-question, namely to do a *tree-filter* that adds the `.gitattributes` and then performs a `git reset`. Without the reset the history would remain unchanged. However, apparently the index is still at the HEAD revision during the filter operations, so only files that are changed with respect to HEAD are recognized, and only those files are converted according to `.gitattributes` (hence the "NUKE" commit in the demo).

My questions:

1. Is this procedure safe to use, or is it just an accidental outcome of undocumented (or misunderstood) behavior?
2. What is git's index during the *tree-filter* operation? Can commands that alter the index be used in *tree-filter* (I didn't find explicit documentation on this topic)?
3. Bonus question: What exactly causes git to pick up the line ending conversions in this setting? (I'm having a hard time understanding what's going on...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my own experience after receiving [torek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40875387/4852374):

> Is this procedure safe to use, or is it just an accidental outcome of undocumented (or misunderstood) behavior?

This procedure should be safe to use on a case-sensitive POSIX compliant file system. It could, however, be made simpler (see https://github.com/cnaj/demo-crlf-rewrite).

> What is git's index during the *tree-filter* operation? Can commands that alter the index be used in *tree-filter* (I didn't find explicit documentation on this topic)?

Yes. With each step, *tree-filter* sets the index to the content of the current revision and checks it out into a temporary directory. After the filter is run, differences between the index and the working copy are promoted into the index, which then becomes a new revision.

> Bonus question: What exactly causes git to pick up the line ending conversions in this setting? (I'm having a hard time understanding what's going on...)

While *filter-branch* sets the index to each revision that is processed, HEAD stays at the original revision where *filter-branch* was started. This way, the `git reset HEAD` command had the effect of removing every file from the index. After that all files are regarded as changed and the index is updated accordingly, triggering the EOL conversion in the process.

Answer (score 0):

This:

> However, apparently the index is still at the HEAD revision during the filter operations, so only files that are changed with respect to HEAD are recognized ...

is quite wrong, but unfortunately the truth is complicated.

Let's start with the basic fact that `git filter-branch` works by *copying* every filtered commit (and annotated tag, if using a `--tag-name-filter`).  If the resulting copy is bit-for-bit identical to the original commit, the copy winds up having the same hash ID and hence *is* the original, in a very real sense.  Otherwise it's a new commit and is the replacement for the original commit.

Git's index plays several different roles, although the primary one is "to build the next commit".  Therefore, the index does in fact change as `git filter-branch` iterates over every original commit in order to copy it.  However...

> namely to do a *tree-filter* that adds the `.gitattributes` and then performs a git reset.

... there is a problem here.  If you look at [the filter-branch code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-filter-branch.sh#L354-L369) you will see that it runs `git update-index` at the end of running the tree filter.  It does not run `git add`, so it depends on the output from the earlier `git diff-index` and `git ls-files` commands.  All this gets done in a temporary directory that overrides the normal work-tree.

Here we run into the edges of my own personal Git-fu :-) because `git add` and the like invoke the attribute code (in a squirrelly path, via the function `unpack_trees`, called directly from `builtin/reset.c`, and indirectly as called from `diff_cache` as called from `run_diff_index` or `index_differs_from` for various others) in a way that respects the `.gitattributes` file in the work-tree.  It appears, however, that `git update-index` doesn't (this is based on your own observation that your attributes are not getting applied).

Fortunately, there is a likely workaround.  If you explicitly `git add .gitattributes` yourself (instead of, or maybe before if necessary, running `git reset` or maybe another `git checkout-index`), that should get the new file into the index.  Then, if `git update-index` uses the indexed version instead of the temporary tree file (as seems likely based on the source), it will be using the one you intended it to use.

Last:

> What exactly causes git to pick up the line ending conversions in this setting?

This is not very well documented, and the code path here is, if anything, even more complicated.

Basically, all filters, including text / CRLF conversions, are applied at two points: when moving files "out" from the index to the work-tree, or when moving files "in" from the work-tree to the index.

The index *also*, however, holds a set of `stat` data and flags, so that Git will only even look at (much less copy in or out) files that seem likely to be different in the tree than in the index version.

There is a separate flag in the index to mark files "dirty".  This flag gets set when a filter modifies the file during checkout.  Since there's no existing `.gitattributes`on the *initial* checkout, the dirty flag won't be set here.  (But the existence of this flag makes any file that *does* get filtered, much slower to work with.  Hence using a lot of attributes makes Git much slower, by defeating the clever index cacheing.)

Comment: It took me some time to process your comment :-) Thanks for pointing me to the git source! Indeed `git update-index` does call the attribute conversion, which happens in `sha1_file.c`: `index_path()`. The attributes file is read from the work tree. However, `diff-index` in `git-filter-branch.sh` doesn't pick up any changes, until the `git reset` effectively dirties the index for all files, at which point `update-index` does the conversion. Looks quite safe to me, but I'll try it out on the big repository tomorrow...